# PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '- The specified procedure could not be found. in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, sql-server

I would like to change php version to 7.1 and i have an error:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 

    'C:\Program Files\PHP\v7.1\ext\php_sqlsrv_7_nts_x86.dll' - The specified procedure could not be found.
     in Unknown on line 0
```

First think. This is not duplicate question because i checked many similar questions. 
I'm using `IIS`, `PHP 7.1`, and `SQL server` (thats why i need sqlsrv drivers). 
I checked `php.ini` file aready and i change extension-dir path to full path but nothing happens. (Logically if path is a problem why it works with other extensions?  ).
It works with PHP 7.0.7 (all enabled extensions is exactly same)

Update: still won't work but i tried to paste path from error message to file explorer and file already there.

Comment: Check if your configuration is 64 bits or 32bits , it is trying to load a 32bits version , maybe your php is 64 bits version. You can download it on php site https://pecl.php.net/

Comment: @Fky PHP is 7.1 x86 nts, pdo as you can see is also x86nts

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out that PHP 7.0 and PHP 7.1 are not compatible and the mssql PDO drivers are for 7.0.

[Github issue here](https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/issues/191)

Also ensure you including the right 64/86 and ts/nts version.

Answer (score 6):

As from Toby Allen's accepted answer above 7.0 and 7.1 are incompatible,

However Microsoft has released Preview versions of the drivers for 7.1.
This worked for me, hope it helps anyone searching.

Drivers can be found [here under downloads](https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/releases/tag/v4.1.8-preview)

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue yesterday.  The key to the error is the last bit.

> The specified procedure could not be found.

In my case I went through a painful amount of debugging.  The first thing that I noticed was that when I ran a hello world php file, I *didn't* get this error.  That indicated to me it wasn't actually a problem loading the file, it was a problem calling a function *in the file*.

I went in and repeatedly put die() statements in and moved it until it hit the error.  It took awhile but I eventually discovered I was calling sqlsrv_connect with options that were (apparently) now invalid.

So I can't say the exact cause of your issue without seeing the code that actually causes the error, but I hope this at least points you in the right direction.